# Qt Quick 2 : Creating and adding a shared library

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qmake

**SITUATION**

I tried to create a dll for my project, but idk what am i doing wrong.

**1 Step : Create a shared Lib**

I went to `create new project` -> 
   `library` ->
   `c++ library` -> 
   `added some test method that returns a const int` -> 
   `built Realse and Debug versions`

**2 Step : Add lib to my project**

what i did is : `right click on my 'real' project` -> 
`clicked on add Library` -> 
`clicked on 'external library' option` ->
`in 'library path' section browsed to my .so file` ->
`Qt added auto-generated code to my .pro file`

**PROBLEM**

i can NOT access to my header in my library.

here is my `main.cpp`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "StickyNotesCore.h" // <- says error: file not found

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;       

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

my `stickynotescore.h`

```
#ifndef STICKYNOTESCORE_H
#define STICKYNOTESCORE_H

#include "stickynotescore_global.h"
class STICKYNOTESCORESHARED_EXPORT StickyNotesCore
{

public:
    StickyNotesCore();
    int Test();
};

#endif // STICKYNOTESCORE_H
```

my `StickyNotes.pro`

```
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE=material ./app

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-StickyNotesCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/release/ -lStickyNotesCore
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-StickyNotesCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/debug/ -lStickyNotesCore
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-StickyNotesCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/ -lStickyNotesCore

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../build-StickyNotesCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_0_GCC_64bit-Debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../build-StickyNotesCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_0_GCC_64bit-Debug
```

*EDIT*

Folder tree

[image]

Comment: you need to specifiy the correct location for your include path.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez how can i do that?

Comment: go to windows explorer find the location where "stickynotescore.h" is located and in "StickyNotes.pro" replace the INCLUDEPATH AND DEPENDEPATH with the correct folder.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez what is the point of .dll/.so if i have to specify manually where all my files are

Comment: you have to do that when you import the dll, but think you made a mistake when you imported the dll, you didn't specify the correct path initially.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez what happens if i create new headers? Should i go and manually add them there again?

Comment: you just recompile your dll, no need to change anything on the .pro file, you already specified the folder where the header files are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your .pro file replace INCLUDEPATH ad DEPENDEPATH to the path where the .h files for your library is located.

make sure to run `qmake` after make the changes.

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../build-StickyNotesCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_0_GCC_64bit-Debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../build-StickyNotesCore-Desktop_Qt_5_13_0_GCC_64bit-Debug
```

Here is an example of what i on my .pro file.

```
   win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../mylibrary/lib/vc140/x64/ -lMYLIBRARY
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../mylibrary/lib/vc140/x64/ -lMYLIBRARYd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../mylibrary/lib/vc140/Win32/ -lMYLIBRARY

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../mylibrary/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../mylibrary/include
```

Comment: sorry for dumb questions. But what is the point of building the lib if i have to bind it to my folder. I mean the original folder does not include the .dll/.so file. How does this work?

Comment: the point of having creating a library is code reusability, you write the code and you can use it for your other projects. QT doesn't know where to find your library, that is why you have to specify where it is located.